# Getting All Contacts per each Account via Map-List from SOQL - Field must be grouped error

Tags: apex, soql

Good day,

I am writing this simple line of code using Map and List when fetching rows from a SOQL statement:
`select id, AccountId, FirstName from Contact where AccountId !=NULL`

Here is the code I have written:

`Map<id,List<Account>> contactMap = new Map<id,List<Account>>(); List<Contact> contactList = [Select count(Id), AccountId, FirstName from Contact WHERE AccountId !=null GROUP BY FirstName];`

Here's the parsing section:

`Contact[] totalNumberOfContact = contactList.get(Id);`
`Contact[] AccoundID = contactMap.get(Id);`
`Contact[] anyContactFirstName = contactList.get(FirstName);`

The for-loop section:

`for(id aid : contactMap.keySet()){ system.debug('Account '+eid+' has '+totalNumberOfContacts+' contacts. One of the contacts is '+anyContactFirstName); }`

But I kept getting this error:

`Field must be grouped or aggregated: AccountId`

May I know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `COUNT(ID)` or other aggregate functions, it changes the query from the original sObject to an AggregateResult. At this point, you have to use all aggregate functions or group by:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), AccountId FROM Contact GROUP BY AccountId
```

However, if you want a *list* of those contacts, and not just how many there are per account, you need to do some post processing.

```
Map<Id, List<Contact>> contactsByAccountId = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
for(Contact record: [SELECT AccountId, Name FROM Contact WHERE AccountId != null]) {
  List<Contact> contactRecords = contactsByAccountId.get(record.AccountId);
  if(contactRecords == null) {
    contactRecords = new List<Contact>();
    contactsByAccountId.put(record.AccountId, contactRecords);
  }
  contactRecords.add(record);
}
```

Which would change your last code to:

```
for(Id accountId: contactsByAccountId.keySet()) {
  List<Contact> contactsForAccount = contactsByAccountId.get(accountId);
  System.debug('Account with Id '+accountId+' has '+contactsForAccount.size()+' contact(s).');
  System.debug('One contact for this account has the name '+contactsForAccount[0].Name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox!

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `GROUP BY` keyword, all of the fields you specify in the `SELECT` clause need to either be:

- Involved in an aggregate function (COUNT(), AVG(), MAX(), MIN(), etc...)
- Appear in the list of fields in `GROUP BY` (yes, you can group by more than one field)

AccountId satisfies neither, so you get your error.

Using `GROUP BY` isn't the right approach when you want to gather a list of child records (Contact) for each parent record (Account).

All you really need is the Id of the parent record, and a `Map<[Parent record Id], List<[Child type]>>`.

As an example:

```java
Map<Id, List<Opportunity>> accountIdToChildOpps = new Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>();

for(Opportunity opp :[SELECT Id, Name, AccountId FROM Opportunity]){
    // Basic map population pattern
    // If the key doesn't exist in the map, we add it to the map
    // That way, after this IF, we're guaranteed to have something in the map we can use
    if(!accountIdToChildOpps.containsKey(opp.AccountId)){
        accountIdToChildOpps.put(opp.AccountId, new List<Opportunity>());
    }

    // This idea, using Map's .get() method and then directly altering the value
    //   (here, by calling .add() on the resulting list) works because the map stores
    //   the Lists "by reference".
    // This doesn't work on Maps where the value type is a primitive type (Integer, Boolean,
    //   Decimal, etc...) because primitive values are stored "by value".
    accountIdToChildOpps.get(opp.AccountId).add(opp);
}
```

The number of child records for any given parent Id is simply the size of the list contained in the map for that parent Id.

There is also a simpler way to go about this. SOQL can get you an embedded list of child records if you use a parent-child subquery.

```
List<Account> accountListWithOpps = [
    SELECT 
        Id, Name,
        // This is the subquery, basically a query inside of a query
        // You can have multiple subqueries, but they can't be nested inception-style
        // The object name you use in the FROM clause is the "child relationship name"
        // In many cases, it'll just be the plural of the child object name (with
        //   '__r' instead of '__c' if it's a custom relationship field)
        (SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunities)
    FROM
        Account
];
```

The caveat with using SOQL to do the heavy lifting here is that you can run into an issue retrieving child records if a single parent has more than 200 children. The safe way to handle subqueries is with a nested for loop.

```java
Map<Id, List<Opportunity>> accountIdWithOppsMap = new Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>();

for(Account acct :[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunities) FROM Account]){
    List<Opportunity> childOpps = new List<Opportunity>();

    // Nested for loops are not inherently evil
    // In this situation, this is the safe way to handle subquery results
    for(Opportunity opp :acct.Opportunities){
        childOpps.add(opp);
    }

    accountIdWithOppsMap.put(acct.Id, childOpps);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Derek! Wow, I never thought it was possible to use nested `for-loops` (may I know if nested loops are also applicable to switch or do-while, while), aswell as I can also use `group by` in more than one field.

Comment: @Archangel08 You can nest any flow-control construct (for, switch, do-while, while, if/else if/else), though in this particular case, using a `for` loop is the appropriate way to do things. 'for' loops that directly iterate over a query end up calling a hidden method `queryMore()` that returns small-ish chunks of records at a time. This can help keep utilization of the "heap" space down (heap is one of the things Salesforce places a limit on) and, more importantly here, allows us to retrieve all the subquery results without running into an error.